# I can't not seem to successfully overwrite and some other things

Tags: c#, replace, copy, rename, overwrite

So, basically I've created this program and it's copying the selected file to the the company's named folder in the Roaming AppData folder, which isn't so bad. I mean, the setup now isn't so bad but I would like to have more control over it.

```
string fullFileName = item.FileName;
string fileNameWithExt = Path.GetFileName(fullFileName);
string destPath = Path.Combine(Application.UserAppDataPath, fileNameWithExt);
File.Copy(item.FileName, destPath);
```

At the beginning of the program it checks to see if the custom AppData folder is there.

```
public void checkADfolder()
{

    string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

    string specificFolder = Path.Combine(folder, ".program");

    if (!Directory.Exists(specificFolder))
       Directory.CreateDirectory(specificFolder);
}
```

I want the files to go to the AppData folder .program instead of the folder with the Application company name.

Also, I am running into an issue with this. When a user selects a file, and then closes the program and opens the program again and happens to select the same file, it gives an error because the file already exists. I need to have it overwrite all other files when the same file is selected.

Screw it, I'll also ask this to why I am here. 
I need the user selected file to replace another file in the AppData folder and rename the user selected file.

Basically. User selects file. File name is "user.txt". Now it's in Roaming > .program > user.txt
I need that file to replace a file let's say it's called "guest.txt". It's in Roaming > .user > guest.txt
I need to copy and rename "user.txt" to "guest.txt" then replace "guest.txt" in the .user folder.
I hope that explains everything well enough.

I figured I would put everything into one post instead of making multiple. 
I've searched but can not seem to find any answers :/

Comment: Have you googled copying a file? And renaming a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overwrite the file you simply need to use the method here:

[File.Copy Method (String, String, Boolean);](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx;)

To overwrite your other file, simply call the function again like so:

```
File.Copy(@".\Roaming\program\user.txt", @".\Roaming\user\guest.txt", true);
```

Comment: Okay thank you, now I need to have the first variable access the user selected file. Am I able to store the user selected file as a variable or something so that I am able to use it easier?

Comment: Sure here is class that is built for Files: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx If you have the time can you mark the answer as accepted? Thank you.

Comment: I can't get the code thing to work. Crap
So, here is my new code

`code`
string fullFileName = item.FileName;
FileInfo userSelected = new FileInfo(fullFileName);
                string fileNameWithExt = Path.GetFileName(fullFileName);
                string destPath = Path.Combine(Application.UserAppDataPath, fileNameWithExt);
                File.Copy(item.FileName, destPath);
`
Is that right? 
Also, you're very welcome

Comment: Well my honest recommendation is to try it in the debugger, step through the code and see if it works. If you run into a problem, that you can't solve, then please post another question on the site and hopefully someone will be able to assist you with your new question. Have a good day.

Comment: Okay, how can I call the userSelected string in the function File.Copy? I'm trying multiple things, but I can not seem to get it.